# Inverse of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta, inverse-function

Is there an inverse function of the Riemann zeta function? A formula for inverse function is

\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(y) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{y^{n/3}}{n!}\cdot\lim_{ \theta \to 0} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^{\,n-1}}{\mathrm{d} \theta^{\,n-1}} \left(\frac \theta { \sqrt[3]{ \theta - \sin( \theta )} } \right)^n\right).
\end{equation}

Can this help to evaluate the inverse?
If there isn't an inverse for all the complex numbers, is there a formula for the inverse at a specific interval, for example the critical strip?

Comment: The Riemann $\zeta$ function is not injective, for instance $\zeta(-2)=\zeta(-4)=0$, so you have to be more precise about the meaning of *inverse function*, as in the inverse function of $\zeta$ *restricted to this interval/set*.

Comment: We have infinite zeroes in the critical strip, too, so a lack of injectivity once again.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes, I thought that the inverse would be multivalued, but I didn't mention it; but I have also asked that if there is no possible inverse, is there a formula for the inverse at a specific interval.

Comment: I guess that would solve RH instantly, don't you think?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes, by substituting zero and using some sophisticated mathematical techniques...

Comment: Maybe a good starting point is $\zeta$ restricted to the interval $(1,\infty)$.  it is decreasing and bijective there.  So of course it has an inverse there.  But I do not understand how that formula would come in.